# sp_whoisactive resulting an unknown query: "Insert Into <table_name> select *,%%bmk%% from <table_name> option (maxdop 1)"

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

`sp_whoisactive` resulting an unknown query:

```
insert into <table_name> select *,%%bmk%% from <table_name> option (maxdop 1)
```

I have checked the above code block but did not find this code in any of my procedures.
Can anyone please suggest what this query might be doing.

Comment: Looks like table structure modifying - SSMS uses such syntax to copy table data.

Comment: @Avro - so you mean someone tried to alter the table and that resulted in this statement?

Comment: it's a ddl statement that's for sure, could be someone creating or rebuilding an index too

Comment: Yep. [Index rebuild most likely](http://www.sqldbadiaries.com/2010/09/06/select-bmk-from-tablename-while-rebuilding-the-index/)

Comment: A related discussion is [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/786f79bf-7d84-46ae-81f4-5c1a5982e1c2/dmv-parameterization) ;).

Answer (score 2):

This is a clustered index being rebuilt.

%BMK% is the function that maps the old bookmarks to the new.

There is a document here that discusses the process: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/cc966402(en-us).aspx

Answer (score -1):

sp_whoisactive is not a built in SQL Server procedure.

It is a UPD (Used defined Procedure).

Check the procedures on your database or master / msdb