# Unkown query: insert <TableNameX> select *.%%bmk%% from<TableNameX>

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlite, indexing

can someone explain me what this line means:

```
insert <TableNameX> select *,%%bmk%% from<TableNameX>
```

i saw a question about the same but cannot understand what it means.
can someone explain what is this %%bmk%%?
p/s - the insert and the From ,  is the same table .
the Line appeard while dropping and creating indexes on - TableNameX.

Comment: I think that is `insert <TableNameX> select *, %%bmk%% from<TableNameX>` ;).

Comment: Related question is http://stackoverflow.com/q/29506640/4519059 ;).

Answer (score 1):

It's the bulk loading of data associated with SQL Server Reindex operation