# Why does dropping an index cause an insert statement to be executed?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, constraints

I'm dropping an index on SQL Server. It takes a long time to drop. Using sp_whoisactive, I see that my SPID is actually executing an INSERT statement on the table!? Any idea what is going on?

SQL sent to the server:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ODS_ORC_Parties] DROP CONSTRAINT [PK_ODS_ORC_Parties]
```

Code being executed:

```
insert [dbo].[ODS_ORC_Parties] select *, %%bmk%% from [dbo].[ODS_ORC_Parties]
```

Surely dropping an index (a) should be pretty quick and (b) shouldn't execute an insert statement.

[EDIT] The following explains what is happening: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/157317/what-happens-when-you-delete-a-clustered-index-and-non-clustered-index-once-crea. In short when a clustered index is dropped, all the other indexes need to be rebuilt to point to the rows in the heap where they previously pointed to the clustered index entries.

Comment: An existing answer is _It's the bulk loading of data associated with SQL Server Reindex operation_. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45636191/2169762

Comment: It seems you drop a clustered index so your clustered table becomes a heap - a different structure that has to be rebuilt.

Comment: Can you post the table's ddl?

Comment: [What happens when we dropped a Cluster index and Non Clustered Index once they are created](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/157317/what-happens-when-you-delete-a-clustered-index-and-non-clustered-index-once-crea)